# Javascript how to catch an error and also have .then() on the same function

Tags: javascript, axios, xmlhttprequest

The problem is that `.then()` (to show success message) doesn't work if axios gets an error, so I want to have `.catch()` to show an error, but if the axios request does work, I want it to show a succes message

How do I write this function so it would `.catch()` errors and also have `.then()`?

I want to add this piece of code:

```
.then(() => 
            {
                swal({
                    title: "Message sent successfully!",
                    type: "success" 
                }).then(function(){
                    location.reload()
                })
            })
```

To this function:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5291/api/Mail', {
        "to": url,
        "subject": document.getElementById("ContactSubject").value,
        "body": `<h3>From:</h3> ${document.getElementById("ContactEmail").value} <br>
                 <h4>Name:</h4> ${document.getElementById("ContactName").value} <br>
                 <h4>Message:</h4> ${document.getElementById("ContactMessage").value}`
    }).catch((error)=> {
        swal("Something went wrong!" , `${error.message}` , "error")
        .then(function(){
            location.reload()
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can totally do both:

```js
axios.post(...)
  .then(res => alert('Success'))
  .catch(err => alert('Error'))
```

And if you want to do something in *both* success & error cases, you can add `finally` clause like this:

```js
axios.post(...)
  .then(res => alert('Success'))
  .catch(err => alert('Error'))
  .finally(() => alert('Processed'))
```

Comment: Oh wow.  I was thinking that if I wrote it like this, then .catch() would try to look for errors inside .then()... Thank you for your response!

Comment: Yeah a Promise is a weird thing. It works differently than most other JavaScript language features. From the syntax itself, it looks like `.then` and `.catch` are function calls and both will be called but in reality, what is called depends on the promise's result. Weird and nice! (If you got your answer, please accept it)